# Image repeates in every cell of table view in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

**My JsonData**  -

```
let imagestring : String? = (myData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Post_mid_image") as? String
if imagestring != nil {
    let imageTrueString = "https://www.zdoof.com/" + imagestring!
    self.imageStringArray.append(imageTrueString )
}
if let NameString = (myData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Name") as? String {
    self.nameStringArray.append(NameString)
}
```

**When i am trying to set it to the table view cell**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return self.postLableArray.count 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reUse", for: indexPath)
    let myImage = cell.viewWithTag(30) as! UIImageView
    myImage.clipsToBounds = true
    if indexPath.row < imageStringArray.count {
        if let myImageString = imageStringArray[indexPath.row] as? String {
            let ImageUrl = URL.init(string: myImageString)
            myImage.kf.setImage(with: ImageUrl)

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

The image is repeating in every cell . Why it is happening ? Please help

Comment: Could you show the JSON data the response which you are receiving.

Comment: You have given the condition as `if indexPath.row < imageStringArray.count`, so for every cell the image will show. What exactly is your requirement? @Tapan

Comment: I am trying to show all the post of a social app. There , some post have images and some has no image . But every post has comments .  "postLableArray " is the array of comments  and  "imageStringArray" is the array containing images.

Comment: my json url  -                                  http://www.zdoof.com/api/reports/post_report?Created_by=4490

Comment: Are you using custom cell?

Comment: I think problem is that same imageView is being returned for the cell as you are setting the image using `viewWithTag` and it is set for only first cell and for others in your particular case there is no url so same image is returned for each cell

Comment: No .I am not using custom cell

Comment: Then , how avoid the problem ?

Comment: Try this code: `cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: ImageUrl)` instead of `myImage.kf.setImage(with: ImageUrl) ` , and see if it helps

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: what is (imageView) here ? Are you saying to not use (viewWithTag)

Comment: `imageView` is a property of default `UITableViewCell` and yes I think you should not use `viewWithTag` have you tried the above code?

Comment: No , let me try

Comment: Actually , I have more than one image in the table view cell . so how to detect the image view without   viewWithTag

Comment: Does the image repeat when you tried the above code?

Comment: I have not tried .beacuse I can't detect the particular image. Due to more than one image in my table view cell

Comment: SDWebImage works like a charm. For Image `displaying` and `caching`   SDWebImage is the best approach [Here is the link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

As per the response you have given, you can show the image like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dict = myData as AnyObject
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reUse", for: indexPath)
    let myImage = cell.viewWithTag(30) as! UIImageView
    if dict["Post_mid_image"] != nil {
        let imageUrl = URL.init(string: strImageUrl)
        myImage.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)
    } else {
        //Set placeholder image showing no image available
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with cell re-usablity of table view here ,you have to handle it , you can have SDWebImage library for loading images in cell or you can have your own image cache which caches images with key/values , key as in image url , so dynamically checking image url for item at indexpath and load cached image with that image url as key.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of using `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reUse", for: indexPath)`.

Basically whenever you use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:,For:)`, it will use the same cell for all of data. It means the total number of cell which are on screen are only going to load, for all other cell, it will use same cell with different value.

now consider a scenario that you are having 500 cells in tableview, but we can manage at most 10-15 cells in display, so for all other cells it will use same cells just modify the value of cell.

so what you can do here is, whenever you use `if` statement, don't forgot to add `else` too.

because for one scenario if cell's background is set to red, than we need to add else for another scenario, as cells are just repeated.